# How do I delete a relationship using Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Am trying to get the basics down before moving forward with neo4j. Love the querying aspect but now trying to delete using neo4jclient and stuck.

Simple setup
root-[:has_user]->user 
and 
user-[:friends_with]->friend`

For a user with the Id of 1 I would like to remove the specified from Id == 2. User 1 is no longer friends with User 2 :(

Anyway, using neo4jclient I first check to make sure that the users are friends in the first place with this:

```
if (client.Cypher.Start("root", client.RootNode)
    .Match("root-[:HAS_USER]->user-[:FRIEND]->friend")
    .Where((UserNode user, UserNode friend) => user.Id == 1 && friend.Id == id)
    .Return<Node<UserNode>>("user")
    .Results
    .Count() == 1)
{
```

now I'm trying to delete:

```
    client.Cypher.Start("root", client.RootNode)
        .Match("root-[:HAS_USER]->user-[r]->friend")
        .Where("user.Id = 1")
        .And()
        .Where("friend.Id = " + id)
        .And()
        .Where(string.Format("type(r) = 'FRIEND'"))                
        .Delete("r");
}
```

No errors, but the relationship is still there. Any ideas?

**Update 11/12/2012**

Got it working. I first updated by Neo4J instance with the **stable 1.8**. I think something with the latest neo4jclient and neo4j server were not working together. I first got the user's node based on the id, then from that node tested if the node had a relationship, then was able to remove it. Code below:

```
        var currentUserNode = client.Cypher.Start("root", client.RootNode)
            .Match("root-[:HAS_USER]->user")
            .Where((UserNode user) => user.Id == 1)
            .Return<Node<UserNode>>("user")
            .Results.Single();

        if (currentUserNode.StartCypher("user")
                .Match("user-[r]->friend")
                .Where("friend.Id = " + id).And()
                .Where("type(r) = 'FRIEND'")
            .Return<Node<UserNode>>("user")
            .Results
            .Count() == 1)
        {

            currentUserNode.StartCypher("user")
                .Match("user-[r]->friend")
                .Where("friend.Id = " + id).And()
                .Where("type(r) = 'FRIEND'")
                .Delete("r").ExecuteWithoutResults();
        }
```

Comment: if you run the pure cypher query in console does it work?

Comment: good idea, ulkas, I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to switch to use a CypherFluentQuery instead:

```
new CypherFluentQuery(client)
    .Start("root", client.RootNode)
    .Match("root-[:HAS_USER]->user-[r]->friend")
    .Where("user.Val = 1").And()
    .Where("friend.Val = " + 2).And()
    .Where("type(r) = 'FRIEND'")
    .Delete("r").ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

which will do what you want.

I believe this all stems from a bug: https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/40/should-be-able-to-add-cypher-delete-clause

As to why `client.Cypher.Start` isn't working as it should, I'm not sure, the bug is fixed, and should be working from version 1.0.0.479 (current at time of writing is 1.0.0.496)

Comment: I have the latest build 496. Tried just adding on a ExecuteWithoutResults to my existing code and also with your CypherFluentQuery and am getting this: Received an unexpected HTTP status when executing the request.

The query was: START root=node({p0})
MATCH root-[:HAS_USER]->user-[r]->friend
WHERE (user.Id = 1) AND (friend.Id = 2) AND (type(r) = 'FRIEND')
DELETE r

The response status was: 400 Bad Request

The raw response body was: {
  "message" : "expected return clause\n\"DELETE r\"\n ^",
  "exception" : "expected return clause\n\"DELETE r\"\n ^",

Comment: I was running 1.6.1, updated to 1.9.M01 now getting: "message":"key not found: user".

Comment: OK, I'm on 1.8, 1.9 is a non-production version, when I switch to a 1.9.M01 db, I too get the error.

As far as I know - neo4jclient supports up to 1.8 at present... It's not a great answer, but I think going with 1.8 is going to give you the best shot...

Comment: I got the error at the console, so it looks like neo4j is changing a bit or something? I was able to put where's on the ends but not the "user" part of the match. I'll go back to 1.8.

Comment: try to put the "cypher 1.8" prefix to the command and run it again in the console. i too have to do that many times to actually force cypher to use the version 1.8 which supports many of the syntax features

Comment: You'd think they would have this working already, I wonder why in later versions it seems so broken. If anything, these projects sure are changing a ton. :P

Comment: Release 1.9 was released primarily to look at the the High Availability stuff they are working on, problems with Cypher etc might be in there until it's RTM'd, For consistency sake - I would only work on 1.8 for now.

Comment: Please don't instantiate `CypherFluentQuery` directly. Just call `client.Cypher`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use any Neo4jClient build after 1.0.0.500. See [issue 45](https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/45) if you're interested in why.
2. Don't forget to call `ExecuteWithoutResults`. The first code sample in your question is missing this. This is documented on https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/wiki/cypher